# how to make the mapping for playframework template?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2, slick, slick-2.0

I use slick2.0 not 1.0
In playframework2.2 template:

val subject = TableQuery[Subjects]

```
@import scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple._
@main(message) {
@*if(@adlist.size>0){
    @views.html.main("some thing"){<div></div>}*@
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function () {
        $('.rating select').barrating({ showSelectedRating:false });
    });
</script>

@slides("sssdfdes")
<div class="list-group">
@for(subitem<-(subject.drop(0).map(i => (i.id, i.name, i.describe,i.sub_resource)).run)){
@topicelement("//localhost/shop/"+subitem._1, subitem._2, 1, subitem._1, subitem._3,subitem._4)
```

}

```
</div>
```

}

the error is:

```
[info] Loading project definition from G:\testprojects\slickplay\project
[info] Set current project to slickplay (in build file:/G:/testprojects/slickpla
y/)
[info] Compiling 5 Scala sources to G:\testprojects\slickplay\target\scala-2.10\
classes...
[error] G:\testprojects\slickplay\app\views\list_subject.scala.html:23: could no
t find implicit value for parameter session: scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend#Sessio
nDef
[error]                       .map(i => (i.id, i.name, i.describe,i.sub_resource
 )).run)){
[error]
 ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 9 s, completed 11/04/2014 4:39:26 AM
actually the problem is:

type mismatch;  found   : scala.slick.lifted.Column[String]  required: String
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not executing your query. You have to execute a Slick query using `.run` before it gives you results:

```
@for(subitem<-(subject.drop(0)
                      .map(i => (i.id, i.name, i.describe,i.sub_resource))
                      .run )){
  @topicelement(
    "//localhost/shop/"+subitem._1, subitem._2, 1, subitem._1, subitem._3,subitem._4
  )
}
```

Comment: [error] G:\testprojects\slickplay\app\views\list_subject.scala.html:24: value run is not a member of scala.slick.lifted.Query[(scala.slick.lifted.Column[Int], s
cala.slick.lifted.Column[String], scala.slick.lifted.Column[String], scala.slick
.lifted.Column[String]),(Int, String, String, String)]

Comment: You are lacking the `.simple._` import from your Slick driver. Not sure how to do this in a play template. You may want to pass the results into the template, instead of the query.

Comment: I added the import scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple._ see my my updated question, but there is still error for scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend

Comment: You need a session. Please read the documentation: http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.1/gettingstarted.html#database-connection

Comment: do you know how to add a session in template?

Comment: No, but there should be a way to embed Scala code. But as I said, you would probably be better of running the query in your controller and passing the result to the view.